# W-iFi is unavailable in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

My laptop: Toshiba Satellite C55-A-1HN
Wireless driver: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless

Link: https://www.linux.org/threads/wireless-lan-hard-blocked-yes.37703/

After a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04.01 my WIFI became unavailable. That is quite frustrating since I have had a similar problem. Please help me fix that.

Results of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` :

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]:Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0612]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Results of `sudo rfkill list` :

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: "Wireless LAN Hard blocked: yes" This suggests that the wireless switch, also known as Airplane Mode, is switched *off*. Find it and switch it.

Comment: Hi @chili555 ! Thanks for your comment. After a second thought, I came to realize that you were right. Indeed, my problem was as you suggested that my WIFI antenna was switched off. Thanks again... cheers.

Comment: Wifi is always on in Dell laptops. There is no antenna button.

Comment: @Mahler May I have a model number where no wireless switch is provided?

Comment: @chili555 Dell Inspiron 06F315

Comment: @Mahler Google says that's a motherboard available on Ebay. Do you have a link to the user manual?

Comment: @chili555 Sorry. I don't want to share this information all over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of the question's author which was originally posted in the question:

Make sure your Wi-Fi antenna is working (switched ON) by pushing the button with the antenna symbol on it as you can see in this image below. On my laptop the Fn+F12 keys turn the Wi-Fi ON and OFF.

[image]

This is quite a major problem: In Ubuntu, you can have the "physical" antenna *turned OFF* while having the Airplane Mode *switched OFF*. In this scenario you have no idea that your Wi-Fi is disabled, and that the only thing you need to do in order to use Wi-Fi is to push the antenna button on your keyboard as shown in the above image.